# How to convert to float if there are tons of lines?

Tags: c#

I've got decompiled source codes, they got simple errors like below:

```
this.SubReport.Top = 77.0 / 16.0;
```

> Error 18  Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)

The solution is simple:

```
this.SubReport.Top = (float)(77.0 / 16.0);
// or 
this.SubReport.Top = 77.0f / 16.0f;
```

However there are tons of lines. What is the easiest way to clear these errors except replacing text? Because that's why I'm asking the question, I don't want to use keyboard & replace every single error, there are 1000+ lines. Doubleclicking the error & surrounding the numbers with (float) is my last resort.

Comment: declare `this.SubReport.Top` as **float**.

Comment: Change `this.SubReport.Top` to a float.

Comment: You could either change the types of the properties you're setting to `double`, or add `f` after each number - `77.0f / 16.0f` will give a float.

Comment: @mehdi You mean as `double`.

Comment: I don't want to use the keyboard for hours.

Comment: Do a search-and-replace for `.SubReport.Top = ` to `.SubReport.Top = (float)`, eyeball it so you don't accidentally insert a cast where it's not needed. (That said changing the type of the property is probably better. It's rarely a good idea to use `float`s instead of `double`s in your code unless you're interacting with hardware that expects `float`s specifically, precisely because C# does floating point calculations with `double`s by default.)

Comment: @millimoose good solution, `Ctrl+H`

Comment: I cannot change .Top as float, it's a 3rd party control's property. JetBrains should fix this.

Comment: You should use `Ctrl+H` and just global replace it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Find & Replace with RegEx options

Example:

[image]

```
Input: this.SubReport.Top = 77.0 / 16.0;
Output: this.SubReport.Top = (float)(77.0 / 16.0);
```

---

### Edit:

Also you could use groups to add the float `f` to the values other than casting

[image]

```
Input: this.SubReport.Top = 77.0 / 16.0;
Output: this.SubReport.Top = 77.0f / 16.0f;
```

Comment: Seems nice, I'll give it a try. Can we confirm that it's a division? and / should be there just before replace? I think I can add @kkokosa 's Find what input.

Comment: this should work for division `this.SubReport.Top = {.+./.+};`

Answer (score 2):

Try to help yourself and automate *Find and Replace* with regular expressions. For example, you can change all divides:

[image]

Then find other such patterns to replace them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to change Top to a property with a double type. Then, inside the property you can do the casting.

```
float _top = 0.0;
double Top
{
    set
    {
        _top = (float)value;
    }
    get
    {
        return _top;
    }
}
```

You could also use something like Resharper to refactor code paths that access the getter for Top and introduce another property in its place as a floating point type that returns (float)Top in its property. Something like:

```
float FloatTop
{
    get
    {       
        return (float)Top;
    }
}
```